# Eta product of squared tau function

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, theta-functions

The Ramanujan tau function is the coefficient of the 24th power of the Dedekind eta function.
$$  \eta(x)^{24}= x\prod_{m=1}^\infty (1 - x^m)^{24} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau(n)\,x^n , $$
I want to know if $\tau(n)^2$  also corresponds to an eta product, if so, what is it?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau(n)^2\,x^n=? $$
For a general power of tau $\tau(n)^k$ where integer $k>2$ is there a corresponding eta product? I tried to find references but didn't find relevant papers.

Comment: The Dirichlet series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau(n)^2 / n^s$ is the tensor square $L$-function $L(\Delta \otimes \Delta,s)$ where $\Delta$ is the cusp form of level 1 and weight 12. This $\Delta \otimes \Delta$ is not a classical modular form but rather an automorphic form on $\mathrm{GL}(2) \times \mathrm{GL}(2)$.